# How can we reset the content of console using python?

Tags: python, command-line, console

```
import threading
import time
import os

def clearAfter15():
    clear = lambda: os.system('clear/cls')
    clear()

string_variable="This message will be disappear after 1 minutte"
t = threading.Timer(1*60, clearAfter15)
t.start()
print(string_variable)
```

**Expected : After 1 minute the output will get disappeared from the console**

Comment: What is your question? Aside from that, this looks like you originally had a function which was intended to clear after a delay, but has since been changed to make it just clear immediately, with the result that the function name is now misleading and it pointlessly defines a lambda and calls it rather than simply calling `os.system` straight off. Could do with tidying up. Still, your code appears to work (though is not portable so on Linux I needed to use `clear` instead of `cls`) - so again, what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def clearAfter15():
    clear = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    clear()
```